# Can I see what's going on in a tmux session without attaching to it?

Tags: tmux

Often I'll use `tmux` to start a task that will be running for a while. I will periodically go back and check on it using `tmux -a` and then disconnect if it still hasn't completed and check again later.

Is there any way to just see a brief snapshot of what's going on in the session without fully attaching? I'm looking for something like theoretically doing a `tail` on the session to get the last bit of output ( but if I can avoid creating another file with a copy of the output all the better )

Maybe attaching and having it immediately detach would also work. I'm attempting to save keystrokes, perhaps such a command could be executed remotely,
i.e. `ssh root@server tmux --tail` ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think `capture-pane` might suit your needs:

```
tmux capture-pane -pt "$target-pane"
```

(see “target-pane” in the man page for the ways to specify a pane)

By default, that command will dump the current contents of the specified pane. You can specify a range of lines by using the `-S` and `-E` options (start and end line numbers): the first line is 0, and negative numbers refer to lines from the pane’s “scroll back” history. So adding `-S -10` gets you the most recent ten lines of history plus the current contents of the pane.

```
tmux capture-pane -pt "$target-pane" -S -10
```

---

The `-p` option was added in 1.8. If you are running an earlier version then you can do this instead:

```
tmux capture-pane -t "$target_pane" \; save-buffer - \; delete-buffer
```

But mind those semicolons if you are issuing this command via `ssh` since the remote shell will add an additional level of shell interpretation (the semicolons need to be passed as arguments to the final *tmux* command, they must not be interpreted by either the local or the remote shell).

Comment: You really own this tag... Great answer (as usual).

Comment: One can also add `-e` for ANSI escapes (color and so on). That makes for a nice mnemonic `-pet`

Comment: That's great! With just one pane `tmux capture-pane -p` is enough to get a quick glance at it.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. One approach that springs to mind is to start your long running process (`$lrp`) and then, periodically, without re-attaching, running `list-windows` for the relevant session.

At some point, the name of the tmux window with $lrp will change back to the default, generally your shell, and you will be able to see that $lrp has completed.

```
┌─[Veles ~]
└─╼ tmux list-windows -t 0
0: App1  (1 panes) [142x51] [layout b27d,142x51,0,0,0] @0
1: SSH  (1 panes) [142x51] [layout b27e,142x51,0,0,1] @1
2: IRC  (1 panes) [142x51] [layout b27f,142x51,0,0,2] @2
3: Shell- (1 panes) [142x51] [layout b280,142x51,0,0,3] @3
4: $lrp* (1 panes) [142x51] [layout b281,142x51,0,0,4] @4 (active)
┌─[Veles ~]
└─╼ tmux list-windows -t 0
0: App1  (1 panes) [142x51] [layout b27d,142x51,0,0,0] @0
1: SSH  (1 panes) [142x51] [layout b27e,142x51,0,0,1] @1
2: IRC  (1 panes) [142x51] [layout b27f,142x51,0,0,2] @2
3: Shell- (1 panes) [142x51] [layout b280,142x51,0,0,3] @3
4: bash* (1 panes) [142x51] [layout b281,142x51,0,0,4] @4 (active)
```

Comment: good idea. I'm still confused about `$lrp` though - was that a variable you mentioned? can you give an example of how it would be used? didn't see `$lrp` listed in `man tmux`

Comment: @cwd That is just a placeholder for your process (say `rsync` or whatever)... :)